# How to get count number of each individual item

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, count

I have the following 2 tables named ROOM and SESSION respectively.

```
ROOM

BUILDINGNO | ROOMNO | ROOMCAPACITY
-----------+--------+-------------
B1         | R1     | 121
B1         | R2     | 253
B2         | R1     | 275
B2         | R2     | 126
B2         | R3     | 124
B3         | R1     | 256    
B3         | R2     | 324
B4         | R1     | 431
B4         | R2     | 345
B4         | R3     | 231


SESSION

SESSIONID | BUILDINGNO | ROOMNO | SPEAKERID
----------+------------+--------+----------
SS01      | B1         | R1     | S1
SS02      | B2         | R1     | S2
SS03      | B1         | R2     | S2
SS04      | B4         | R2     | S4
SS05      | B3         | R2     | S5
SS06      | B3         | R1     | S5
SS07      | B4         | R2     | S3
SS08      | B1         | R2     | S2
SS09      | B2         | R3     | S4
SS10      | B4         | R1     | S3
```

I would like to be able to show the number of sessions located in each room. That would ideally show a table of some sort like this.

```
BUILDINGNO | ROOMNO | NUMBEROFSESSIONS
-----------+--------+-----------------
B1         | R1     | 1
B1         | R2     | 2
B2         | R1     | 1
B2         | R2     | 0
B2         | R3     | 1
B3         | R1     | 1  
B3         | R2     | 1
B4         | R1     | 1
B4         | R2     | 2
B4         | R3     | 0
```

I know I need to use the COUNT and JOIN functions somewhere... but I'm a bit stuck to say the least. If anyone could point me in the right direction or explain this to me it would be greatly appreciated :)

```
SELECT BUILDINGNUMBER, ROOMNO FROM ROOM ... COUNT? ... JOIN?
```

Also what would allow me to show/hide the rows where the number of sessions = 0?

Comment: Your table data is not normalized.

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have added CONSTRAINT ROOM_PK PRIMARY KEY(BUILDINGNO,ROOMNO)

Comment: @james That isn't normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in the number of sessions within each room, then I believe you have enough information in the *SESSION* table.

```
SELECT BUILDINGNO, ROOMNO, COUNT(*)FROM SESSION 
GROUP BY BUILDINGNO, ROOMNO;
```

[Here is a sql fiddle:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b40d/12)

Answer (score 0):

You could use count(distinct sessionid)

```
SELECT ROOM.BUILDINGNO , ROOM.ROOMNO, count(distinct SESSION.sessionid)
from ROOM 
left join SESSION on ROOM.ROOMNO = SESSION.ROOMNO 
     and ROOM.BUILDINGNO = SESSION.BUILDINGNO 
group by  ROOM.BUILDINGNUMBER, ROOM.ROOMNO
```

and for hide room with resul = 0  you can use having

```
SELECT ROOM.BUILDINGNO , ROOM.ROOMNO, count(distinct SESSION.sessionid)
from ROOM 
left join SESSION on ROOM.ROOMNO = SESSION.ROOMNO 
     and ROOM.BUILDINGNO = SESSION.BUILDINGNO 
group by  ROOM.BUILDINGNUMBER, ROOM.ROOMNO
HAVING count(distinct SESSION.sessionid) >0
```

but you have enough info in the tables sessions

```
SELECT SESSION.BUILDINGNO , SESSION.ROOMNO, count(distinct SESSION.sessionid)
SESSION 
group by  SESSION.BUILDINGNO , SESSION.ROOMNO
HAVING count(distinct SESSION.sessionid) >0
```

Comment: `SELECT ROOM.BUILDINGNO, ROOM.ROOMNO
COUNT(DISTINCT SESSION.SESSIONID)
FROM ROOM LEFT JOIN SESSION 
ON ROOM.ROOMNO = SESSION.ROOMNO 
AND ROOM.BUILDINGNO = SESSION.BUILDINGNO 
GROUP BY  ROOM.BUILDINGNO, ROOM.ROOMNO;`

Thanks! :) That give me what I want. How would I hide the rows where the count is 0?

Comment: explain better you comment  ..  is don't understand

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.BUILDINGNO, r.ROOMNO, count(1) QQ
FROM ROOM r, SESS s
WHERE 
r.ROOMNO = s.ROOMNO
AND r.BUILDINGNO = s.BUILDINGNO
GROUP BY r.BUILDINGNO, r.ROOMNO
ORDER by r.BUILDINGNO;
```

[DEMO][1]
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb290/6